# Blazor Server App - schedule a routine task

Tags: .net, blazor

I have a Blazor Server .Net 6 app.  I have a function in this app that I would like to be called every hour.  In the past I have created a Windows Server Scheduled Task to call a web page that executes the function.  I was wondering if there was any nice assemblies/methods I could add to my app that would allow me to do this instead.   The other alterantive was to create an Azure Function but I thought i would investigate what I can do within the relms of my Blazor Server App first.

TIA

Comment: You could use a hangfire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom service with a timer for this. For example:

```
public class ExampleService : IDisposable
{
    public Timer? CheckTimer { get; set; }
    public async Task RunTimer()
    {
        CheckTimer = new Timer(async (e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Check();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        },null,0, 30000); // define interval here
    }

    public async Task Check()
    {
        // DO YOUR STUFF HERE 
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        CheckTimer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

In your Program.cs start the service:

```
await builder.Services.GetRequiredService<ExampleService>().RunTimer();
```

Comment: Thanks ever so much.  Looks great.  I ended up using HangFire which seemed to have lots of features